# JavaFX TableView Population

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I've been following the JavaFX TableView tutorial on oracle.com,
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm

But I cannot seem to get my table to populate, I'm trying to do a simple password manager.

I did a simple test object for the ObservableList, but even that won't show up.

This is my 'Credentials' class:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

// Simple class for holding credentials

class Credentials {

private final SimpleStringProperty Username;
private final SimpleStringProperty URL;
private final SimpleStringProperty Password;

public Credentials(String x, String y, String z) {
    this.URL = new SimpleStringProperty(x); 
    this.Username = new SimpleStringProperty(y);
    this.Password = new SimpleStringProperty(z);
}

public String username(){ return Username.get(); }

public String url(){ return URL.get(); }

public String password(){ return Password.get(); }
```

}

This is my application class,

```
public class Crypt32Dec extends Application {

private TableView<Credentials> table = new TableView<Credentials>();
private ObservableList<Credentials> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Credentials("test", "test", "test"));

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    JDec dec = new JDec();
    GridPane grid=new GridPane();

    final Label label = new Label("Password Recovery Tool");
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));
    GridPane.setConstraints(label, 0, 0);
    table.setEditable(true);

    TableColumn URLCol = new TableColumn("URL");
    URLCol.setMinWidth(100);
    URLCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("URL"));

    TableColumn UsernameCol = new TableColumn("Username");
    UsernameCol.setMinWidth(100);
    UsernameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Username"));

    TableColumn PasswordCol = new TableColumn("Password");
    PasswordCol.setMinWidth(200);
    PasswordCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Password"));

    table.setMaxHeight(200);
    table.setItems(data);

    table.getColumns().addAll(URLCol, UsernameCol, PasswordCol);
    GridPane.setConstraints(table, 1, 0);

    final VBox vbox = new VBox();

    vbox.setSpacing(5);
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table);
    grid.getChildren().add(vbox);

    Button btn = new Button();
    Button btn2 = new Button();
    Button btn3 = new Button();
    GridPane.setConstraints(btn, 2, 0);

    btn.setText("Recover Local Passwords");
    btn2.setText("Generate Password");
    btn3.setText("Recover External Passwords");
    grid.getChildren().addAll(btn, btn2);

    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
           try {
            ArrayList<Credentials> ChromeDetails = dec.ChromeDec();
            ArrayList<Credentials> FirefoxDetails = dec.FirefoxDec();

            for(Credentials Details : FirefoxDetails){
            data.add(new Credentials(Details.url(), Details.username(), Details.password()));
            }

            } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(grid);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 550);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Password Recovery Tool");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```